# Не работает контекст у стрелочных функций

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
var A = {
    name: 'A',
    allCallbacks: [],
    setCallback: function( callback ){
        this.allCallbacks[0] = callback;
    },
    say: function( ){
        this.allCallbacks[0]( );
    }
};

var B = {
    run: function( ){
        A.setCallback( ( ) => this.sayName( ) );
    },
    sayName: function( ){
        console.log('B');
    }
};

B.run();
A.say();
```

На [хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/company/mailru/blog/213455/) прочел, что самым главным преимуществом стрелочных функций является связывание контекста. Но код выше этого не подтвердил. Почему?

**UPD: 0.1.0**
Так я и получаю ошибку -

```
F:\projects\projects\test\test.js:15
        A.setCallback( ( ) => this.sayName( ) );
                                   ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Array.<anonymous> (F:\projects\projects\test\test.js:15:36)
    at Object.A.say (F:\projects\projects\test\test.js:9:29)
    at Object.<anonymous> (F:\projects\projects\test\test.js:23:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:446:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:464:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:341:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:296:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:487:10)
    at startup (node.js:111:16)
    at node.js:799:3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, вы запутали себя своим же примером. Ваш код работает верно и он безусловно подтверждает передачу контекста, в чем вы можете убедиться, сравнив [es6](http://jsfiddle.net/orp5ojak/) и [es5](http://jsfiddle.net/7cqxtxge/) стиль.

В этом случае:

```
A.setCallback( ( ) => this.sayName( ) );
```

`this` как раз-таки несет в себе контекст объекта `B`, поэтому вызов функции `sayName()` возможен. В противном случае, `this` ссылался бы на глобальный контекст (в случае браузера - `window`) и вы бы получили ошибку.

Comment: Добавил ошибку к вопросу. И здесь ещё хочу добавить, что на данный момент у меня только флаг --harmony_arrow_functions. Может ещё какой нужен? Хотя ещё и --use_strict.

Comment: С этим вопросом не помогу, лучше погуглите про флаги и их поддержку в вашей версии nodejs. Слышал, что там не все так гладко, в свете чего и появился форк io.js

Comment: Так у меня и стоит iojs, просто здесь тега такого нет, вот и указал nodejs. Я гуглил и ничего не нашел. Думал, что здесь есть те, кто пишет на iojs... Но как видно, iojs-nodejs только для личного баловства.